# Eliminating false positives inside macros in Coverity

Tags: c++, coverity

I'm checking very old C++ code with Coverity that uses a lot of compilcated macros.

Coverity doesn't understand on macro that initializes members. I have checked the code manually and I'm sure it's a false positive, but I can't manage to silence the error.

```
ATTR_INIT(SomeStruct, unsigned, sflags, 0);
```

I tried to put a define into the modeling file

```
#define ATTR_INIT(cls, typ, nam, val) cls::typ nam = val;
```

or

```
#define ATTR_INIT(cls, typ, nam, val) __coverity_writeall__(nam);
```

But neither has removed the error. I also tried a code annotation, but that didn't work either.

Any pointers ?

Comment: You may want to try enclosing the parameters in parenthesis:  `((cls)::(type) (nam) = (val))`

Comment: I recommend against using macros.  If you are writing macros to save typing time, take a keyboarding class.

Comment: @Thomas: I'm with you against macros in new code, but I can't rewrite a huge piece of legacy software that works fine just to remove the macros.

Comment: @Thomas: Unfortunately the brackets didn't help in the modeling file.

Comment: Could you post the supposed FP? Coverity's analysis does take macro information into account for some checkers, however the AST produced will be identical if you'd not used the macro and just wrote the code out instead - this makes me suspect that the issue isn't related to macros at all.

Comment: @Caleb: https://scan7.coverity.com/login/login.htm#v16594/p11247/fileInstanceId=37824972&defectInstanceId=8219321&mergedDefectId=278908